# Get C to read more than one character in a single input

Tags: c, char

I'm new to C, and I'm looking to write a program that takes a word, say "Aloha" as input, notes all the vowels and consonants in the word, and counts the number of characters in the word.

I've created the functions to determine if a single character is a vowel or consonant in the Hawaiian language, but I don't know how to make the program read more than one character as input. For example, in the code below

```
#include <stdio.h>

int is_vowel(char);
int is_consonant(char letter);

int main() {

char letter;
int vowel, consonant;

    printf("Please input a Hawaiian word:");
    scanf("%c", &letter);

    vowel = is_vowel(letter);
    consonant = is_consonant(letter);

    if (vowel == 1) {

        printf("%c is a vowel. \n", letter);
    } else {

        printf("%c is not a vowel. \n", letter);
    }


    if (consonant == 1) {

    printf("%c is a consonant. \n", letter);
} else {

    printf("%c is not a consonant. \n", letter);
}

}
```

when the user inputs "Aloha", the output is
"A is a vowel.
A is not a consonant", then it stops.

Instead of "A is vowel, A is not consonant. l is not a vowel, l is a consonant"  etc etc.

How do I get C to read all the characters in the input one at a time, and get the function (not included in the sample code) to check each of them?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you planning to enforce the correct consonants of the [Hawaiian Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_alphabet) — H, K, L, M, N, P, W — or are you able to ignore this detail?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The OP has already covered this: “I've created the functions to determine if a single character is a vowel or consonant *in the Hawaiian language*” (emphasis added)

Comment: @BrianDrake — But the OP has not shown this knowledge, though I agree it is probably so. And not all readers of the question may be aware of the limited alphabet for Hawaiian. And there's no example output for any non-Hawaiian input — such as `input`.  But it is only comment-worthy (if barely that); which is why it is in a comment. The answers do not demonstrate that knowledge, either.

Answer (score 1):

input should be : a-z or A-Z

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int is_vowel(char ch) {
    if(ch=='a' || ch=='e' || ch=='i' || ch=='o' || ch=='u') return 1;
    else if(ch=='A' || ch=='E' || ch=='I' || ch=='O' || ch=='U') return 1;
    else return 0;
};
int is_consonant(char ch) {
    if(is_vowel(ch) == 0) return 1;
    else return 0;
};

int main()
{
    char letter[100];
    int vowel, consonant;
    int i, length;

    printf("Please input a Hawaiian word: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", &letter);
    length = strlen(letter);

    for(i=0; i<length; i++) {

        vowel = is_vowel(letter[i]);
        consonant = is_consonant(letter[i]);
        if (vowel == 1) {
            printf("%c is a vowel. \n", letter[i]);
        }
        else {
            printf("%c is not a vowel. \n", letter[i]);
        }

        if (consonant == 1) {
            printf("%c is a consonant. \n", letter[i]);
        }
        else {
            printf("%c is not a consonant. \n", letter[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: FYI: the line `scanf("%[^\n]s", &letter);` illustrates _four_ common problems: (1) The `s` is an interloper; a scan set `%[…]` is a complete conversion specification, not a modifier to the `s` conversion specification. (2) You should specify `%99[^\n]` to prevent overflows. (3) You should pass `letter` (type `char *`) and not `&letter` (type `char (*)[100]`) because a scan set expects a `char *` argument. (4) You should check that you got the input you expected: `if (scanf("%99[^\n]", letter) != 1) { …oops; handle error… } else { …proceed… }`.

Comment: The OP has already implemented `is_vowel()` and `is_consonant()` and did not ask for implementations of these functions. You have provided *incorrect* implementations: they are supposed to be for Hawaiian, not English. You have used an interesting optimisation that works for English: A letter is a consonant if and only if it is not a vowel. But you have not taken advantage of this in `main()`, calling both `is_vowel()` and `is_consonant()`. (Edit: The code in `main()` I refer to was copied from the OP.)

Answer (score 0):

Useful tools are:

- Arrays: continuous sequence of variables that can be accessed using index
- `%s` format specifyer: have `scanf()` read strings (NUL-terminated sequence of characters)
- `for(initializer; condition; update) { body }` loop:

  1. execute `initializer`
  2. repeat executing `body` and `update` while `condition` is true

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int is_vowel(char);
int is_consonant(char letter);

int main() {
    char letters[102401]; /* allocate enough size */
    int i;

    printf("Please input a Hawaiian word:");
    if (scanf("%102400s", letters) != 1) { /* read input with length limit and check if it succeeded */
        puts("input error");
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; letters[i] != '\0'; i++) { /* loop over the letters read */
        char letter = letters[i];
        int vowel, consonant;

        vowel = is_vowel(letter);
        consonant = is_consonant(letter);

        if (vowel == 1) {

            printf("%c is a vowel. \n", letter);
        } else {

            printf("%c is not a vowel. \n", letter);
        }


        if (consonant == 1) {

            printf("%c is a consonant. \n", letter);
        } else {

            printf("%c is not a consonant. \n", letter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why have the variable declarations (`letter`, `vowel` and `constant`), which used to be at the start of `main()`, moved into the loop? They were perfectly fine at the start of `main()`, where you have added two more declarations. If you want declarations in the loop for some reason, surely you should do `for (int i = 0; ...)`.

Comment: The OP also wanted to “count[] the number of characters in the word”. So let’s keep `i` defined outside the loop. Now, after the loop, `i` is the index of the terminating null byte. That means `i - 1` is the index of the last character of the string and `i` is the length of the string. So we can write `printf("The number of characters in the word is %i. \n", i);`